# Crystal xi - string numbers together without decimal places

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to build a text field by stringing 2 numbers together for a barcode.

For example: `fld1` is 12345678 and `fld2` is 145.99.
`fld1` needs to be 9 characters long, zero filled and `fld2` needs to be 8 characters long, zero filled.

I need the string to be 01234567800014599

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

There is 2 step to do. One need concatenation, for this '+' is used to concatenate.
For the leading zero you can use Right function (refer below link)

```
ToText({table1.fld1},"000000000") +  ToText({table1.fld1},"000000000")
or
Right("0000"&{table1.fld2},8) + Right("0000"&{table1.fld2},8)
```

just check this link :- [Padding a fixed number with leading zeros up to a fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989266/padding-a-fixed-number-with-leading-zeros-up-to-a-fixed-length)

[Crystal report; Combining rows of data into a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558228/crystal-report-combining-rows-of-data-into-a-single-value)