# How to display column data from multiple rows in a single row in Crystral Reports or SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, crystal-reports

So I have a view that has multiple rows for the same project each row has a description field and a value field and a measurement field Example of the data below
[image: Source Table Data]

what I am trying to achive is getting all this unique data on a single row so it looks like this:
[image]

I hit a road block on everything I have tried so far, I tried building a pivot table but there is no Aggregate function I have found to use with it to achieve this result.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On good way to do this is by using three formulas.

One formula in the group header of ID to initialize your variables.
A second formula in the detail section to Concatenate the data you need.
And another to display the data in the group footer.
You would then suppress the sections you don't want to display.
[The response in this link is a pretty good explanation of the process.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558228/crystal-report-combining-rows-of-data-into-a-single-value)

Comment: thank you for this, but this would make it into a string and what I what to do is make them into new columns in the same row. So the end user and export to excel for analysis

Comment: Looking closer at your request ... would there always be 5 items per ID? Or could there be more or less?

Comment: more or less but it would be a know about based off the category